# Always hide iPhone/iPad graphic bezel from iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

If you build to a simulator with dimensions too large to fit on your screen, it'll throw it into a nice, neat little regular OS window, rather than the "Oh look, it's an iPhone on my screen!" thingy.

I'd like it to always do that, even with a non-retina phone whose dimensions can fit on my display. I don't ever want to see the graphic bezel around the outside.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not show the graphic bezel either change the iOS Simulator device under hardware -> device to iPhone Retina 3.5 inch or iPhone Retina 4 inch. Another solution is you can keep the "iPhone" device setting and change the window scale. Either of these will remove the bezel.

Comment: Will those settings persist across all projects, etc?

Comment: It does for me. The simulator is not tied to a specific project.

Comment: I find that picking device: iPhone - 4 inch and scale of 50% works good for my screen resolution. Might want 75% scale if you have a high resolution screen.